# Excel: assign numbers 1-9 to letters

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've been trying this for a while without success.

- I'm trying to assign the numbers 1-9 to letters of the alphabet A-Z (A=1 B=2 C=3 D=4 E=5 F=6 G=7 H=8 I=9 J=1 K=2 L=3 etc.)
- I want to be able to type a word and have the numbers corresponding to each letter show up, e.g. AND would be 154, FALL would be 6133.
- In another cell I want to be able to sum up the digits of the number, e.g. AND would be 1+5+4 = 10. FALL = 6+1+3+3 = 13.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on your version of Excel, you can use:

```
Digits: =CONCAT(MOD(CODE(MID(H2,SEQUENCE(LEN(H2)),1))-65,9)+1)
Sum:    =SUM(MOD(CODE(MID(H2,SEQUENCE(LEN(H2)),1))-65,9)+1)
```

[image]

If your version does not have the `SEQUENCE` function, you can replace it with:

```
ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,LEN(H2)))
```

If you do not have the `CONCAT` function, VBA might be a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

You can use VBA functions for that:

```vb
Public Function AlphaToDigits(s)
    Dim d As String
    
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        d = d & CStr(((Asc(Mid(s, i, 1)) - 65) Mod 9) + 1)
    Next
    
    AlphaToDigits = d
    
End Function

Public Function SumStringDigits(s)
    Dim n As Long
    
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        n = n + CInt(Mid(s, i, 1))
    Next
    
    SumStringDigits = n
    
End Function
```

For example, with `=AlphaToDigits(A1)` etc. in column B and `=SumStringDigits(B1)` etc. in column C:

[image]

---

In case you haven't discovered macros in Excel, here's Microsoft's instructions on how to create them: [Create custom functions in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f).

Answer (score 0):

1. Your Word say "ORANGE" is there in Cell A1
2. Split the word in single letter, on the right side by entering formula :
3. B1=MID($A$1,1,1);   C1=MID($A$1,2,1);    D1=MID($A$1,3,1).....So on....
4. Leaving One Row, for clarity : In Cell B3 Enter Formula Given in Step 5.
5. B3 =IF(CODE(B1)<=73,CODE(B1)-64,   IF(CODE(B1)<=82,CODE(B1)-73,   IF(CODE(B1)<=90,CODE(B1)-82,0)))
6. COPY Formula of Cell B3, in C3, D3, E3, F3,......etc.
7. For SUM, enter formula in say, M3 = SUM(B3:K3)
8. On entering formula in B3..to G3, we get, values as : 691575 and Sum=33.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Result]

Join: =TEXTJOIN("",,VLOOKUP(MID(D2,SEQUENCE(LEN(D2)),1),$A$2:$B$13,2,0))

Sum: =SUM(VLOOKUP(MID(D2,SEQUENCE(LEN(D2)),1),$A$2:$B$13,2,0))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).